# Construction in return statement

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a class `Foo` with a non-`explicit` constructor from an `int`. Then for the following functions:

```
Foo makeFoo1() { return 123; }
Foo makeFoo2() { return {123}; }
```

I think `makeFoo1` requires that `Foo`'s copy/move ctor is accessible, and it's *possible* (though unlikely) that the compiler does not elide the copy and thus results in a true copy/move.

For `makeFoo2`, since we are using copy-list-initialization, no copy/move can ever occurred.

Should I really worry about this and put arguments to non-`explicit` ctors in braces whenever I can (as in `makeFoo2`)? (Say if I'm a library author and expect the library to be used with subpar compilers for embedded system.)

Comment: _"For makeFoo2, since we are using copy-list-initialization, no copy/move can ever occurred."_ [Really?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38043288/560648)

Comment: No, however the second makeFoo has lesser requirements on the class Foo (no copy whatsoever); hence it is better.

Comment: What copy are you trying to elide?  If you're constructing from an integer, I wouldn't worry about a eliding copying an integer as this will fit into a CPU register.  As for the Foo object, wouldn't that be elided already by RVO?

Comment: @Spacemoose I'm talking about the RVO. It's almost always carried out, but that's not guaranteed by the standard. If I want to make sure no copy is ever made in any case, copy-list-initialization should be the best choice, I guess?

Comment: According to Scott Meyers in Item 25 of Effective Modern C++, the standard indicates that even if the compiler chooses not to perform copy elision, the object being returned must be treated as an rvalue (i.e. returned along the lines of 'return std::move(x);' )

Comment: Note that the C++17 standard will *require* copy elision ("guaranteed copy elision") in this case.

Comment: I would be more concerned about having such implicit constructors in your codebase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb here and combine a practical answer with a weak language-lawyery justification.

The weak language-lawyer argument: If I understand [this cppreference.com description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) correctly, you are not guaranteed RVO when initializing with an initializer list (`makeFoo2`) any more than you are with just your int return (`makeFoo1`). So, don't surround your int in braces.

Practical argument 1: Come one, those braces have *got* to be redundant. They *should* be redundant. So don't use them, it doesn't seem right.

Practical argument 2: The principle of least surprise. Using those braces, you're implying there's something wrong with the brace-less form. I would be confused and slightly surprised by the braces (albeit not very confused).

Practical argument 3: In these kinds of situations - trust the compiler. This is not where your performance bottleneck is (and if it is - make it an inline function, and it won't be; or use a reference if you have an existing object; etc).