# Explicitly calling constructors and destructors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that one should not call destructors explicitly for local members as it results in undefined behaviour. But still I want to understand the output for following piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { cout << "Constructor is executed\n"; }
    ~Test() { cout << "Destructor is executed\n"; }
    friend void fun(Test t);
};
void fun(Test t)
{
    Test(); //3.calls constructor and destructor
    t.~Test(); //4. calls destructor
}
int main()
{
    Test(); // 1. calls constructor and destructor
    Test t; // 2.calls constructor
    fun(t); 
    return 0; //5. compiler calls destructor for t
}
```

Expected output (3 destructor calls at the end):

```
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Constructor is executed
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Actual output (4 destructor calls at the end):

```
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Constructor is executed
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Where is th extra destructor call coming at the end?

Comment: You are passing `t` by value - this creates and destroys a temporary copy. You have not instrumented the copy constructor, so you don't see that call in the output, but you do see the matching destructor.

Comment: Knowing that the behaviour is undefined, but still expecting particular output are contradictory. That said, the reason why there is one more destruction than you expected has nothing to do with the explicit call to the destructor.

Comment: It is okay to call the destructor explicitly, as long as you reconstruct it with placement new after, putting the object back before the compiler calls the dtor on its own at the end of local scope. But just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should ;)

Comment: If you want to see an example of when to call destructor manually, implement `optional<T>` with local storage for `T`. As for constructor, you call them all the time, but I guess you're thinking about placement new, i.e., 'reconstructing' the object.

Comment: Hint: if you want to investigate these kind of behaviours, output the 'this' pointer in your messages and you will be able to draw firmer conclusions about which object's functions are running.

Answer (score 5):

You pass `t` to `fun` by value. It creates a copy.
The reason you don't see that is because you didn't make the copy constructor print anything.
But you do see it destructed.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `t` is passed to the function `fun` by value - therefore an extra copy is constructed on entry to the function (you don't see this printed as your print statement is for default constructor only), and also destructed upon exit (this is the `t` on which you also invoke the destructor explicitly, so it gets destructed twice).

Answer (score 2):

You should at least print address of this in ctor and dtor message. I did it and got:

```
Constructor is executed 0020FC9F
Destructor is executed0020FC9F
Constructor is executed 0020FD77
Constructor is executed 0020FBAB
Destructor is executed0020FBAB
Destructor is executed0020FC84
Destructor is executed0020FC84
Destructor is executed0020FD77
```

This shows that you get an extra object at 20FC84 on which you call destructor twice without seeing it in default constructor. It is because it has been created with an implicit (compiler provided) copy constructor to allow it to be passed by value to function `fun`. If you want to avoid that extra copy just declare `fun` to take its argument by ref:

```
void fun(Test& t)
{
    Test(); //3.calls constructor and destructor
    t.~Test(); //4. calls destructor
}
```

(do not forget the ref in the friend declaration...)

It now gives as expected:

```
Constructor is executed 003EF90F
Destructor is executed003EF90F
Constructor is executed 003EF9E7
Constructor is executed 003EF827
Destructor is executed003EF827
Destructor is executed003EF9E7
Destructor is executed003EF9E7
```

Comment: Just thought to point this out: There was another question recently about `this` pointer changing for objects, so sometimes this printing address of `this` idea can be misleading I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043288/does-the-c-standard-guarantee-that-a-function-return-value-has-a-constant-addr But in general yeah it's a good idea

Answer (score 2):

In this statement in main

```
Test();
```

the constructor and the destructor of the temporary object is called.

So you have

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Then in the next statement in main

```
Test t;
```

the constructor is called and you have

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed Test t in main
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Then in this statement in fun

```
Test();
```

the constructor and the destructor of the temporary object are called and you have

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed Test t in main
Constructor is executed Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  Test() in fun
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Then the destructor is called explicitly in fun

```
t.~Test();
```

and you have

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed Test t in main
Constructor is executed Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  t.~Test() in fun
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

In turn the compiler implicitly calls the destructor for its parameter t after exiting the function

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed Test t in main
Constructor is executed Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  t.~Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  The compiler calls the destructor for parameter t
Destructor is executed
```

And at last the local object t declared in main is also destroyed after exiting main

```
Constructor is executed Test() in main
Destructor is executed  Test() in main
Constructor is executed Test t in main
Constructor is executed Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  t.~Test() in fun
Destructor is executed  The compiler calls the destructor for parameter t
Destructor is executed  The compiler calls the destructor for local object t declared in main
```

Comment: OK. So the extra one which I couldn't figure out was the destructor for parameter t. And the reason, why there is not constructor call for parameter t is because the (default) copy constructor is called (here) in case of passing by value. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

the last destructor was for the fun() that have taken space in to stack Destructor is executed after all the current thread will finish execution it removes the space allocated by the function .